# How do I get my installer to deploy the Visual Studio 2013 (VC120) runtime to Windows XP?

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer, visual-studio-2013, merge-module

I recently updated my application to Visual Studio 2013. I'm attempting to make a final Windows XP build before dropping support, but I'm running into a problem with the installer after changing the installer version from 200 to 405. I had to do this in order to include the VC120 merge modules.

When I try to install my application on Windows XP, I get a dialog saying '*This installation package cannot be installed by the Windows installer service. You must install a Windows service pack that contains a newer version of the Windows Installer service.*' This machine does have the latest service pack, however.

Is there any way for me to redistribute the VC120 runtime to Windows XP alongside my application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the merge modules.  Create a burn bootstrapper bundle that redistributes [this](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784)   instead.  The installation requirements call out XP as acceptable.

[Building Installation Package Bundles](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/)

Comment: What is a "burn bootstrapper bundle" ?

Comment: That's a great question for Google. (Answer Updated) :)

Answer (score 0):

Windows XP SP3 included Windows Installer 3.1 which is likely too old.

There is a separate [Windows Installer 4.5 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=8483) you can use to update an XP system.

Can run `Msiexec` at a commmand line to check the current Windows Installer version (a dialog comes up which shows the version at the top of a text box).

Comment: So it seems like the answer is 'there is no way?'